# Multiple Diagrams in Model vs One large .EDMX vs Multiple .EDMX

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to the entity and How should I struct my Entity model.
We have 600 Database table.
So which options should be preferable DB First or EF First?
Please let me know which one is better and what the pros/cons (if any) of each alternative.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a User table and a Report table.
The Report table has a UserID key to the respective User row.
If you have User in Accounts.EDMX and Report in Reporting.EDMX, you will not have a "User.Reports" nor a "Report.User" navigational property.

As far as I'm concerned, that's the biggest issue in splitting EDMX into multiple files, and the reason I've always added all my tables to a single file...

Comment: Though I have very large Database, So to use only one .EDMX would create any problem(s)?And is it good practice to Create single .EDMX for such large database?

Comment: The only issue with a single large EDMX file is the time it might take Visual Studio to run the code generation tools. Once that is complete though, the code will compile and work just fine.